How to change the color and position of the boxes
I want to change the position and colour of the title and description boxes; how can I do that? Can someone help me to get this?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{description title/.append style={
        signal, 
        signal to=south, 
        signal from=north,
        yshift=-0.65cm, 
    }
}

\begin{center}
    \smartdiagramset{description title width=2cm, 
        description title text width=3.5cm,
        descriptive items y sep=4.2,
        description text width=12.75cm,
        description title width=3cm, 
        description title text width=3.5cm,
        module minimum height=.25cm, 
    }
    \smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
        {\bfseries  Modelling,              
            Model wil be created },
        {\bfseries  Performance Analysis, {
                Performance will be analysed}},
        {\bfseries Validation, 
            Validation will be done},}
\end{center}
\end{document}


Welcome. // If you‘d try to compile this code fragment, it would fail. Please add the missing lines. Thank you

I suggest to have a look into the manual: https://ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram . It provides many examples. Already the first one answers one of your various questions: set color list={ ...

Please specify how you want to change the position.

I want to locate the arrow on the left-hand side horizontally on the same line as the box on the right.
